# GWT How discard changes on a Editor

Tags: gwt, editor

I there a way of Editor discards changes made on its properties? This on client side. No persitence.

I have:

```
public class ClaseEditor extends PopupPanel implements Editor<ClaseProxy> {
  @UiField ValidatedTextBox tema;
  @UiField ValidatedTextBox catedratico;
}
```

I use this editor on a ListEditor as u know there are a list of editors in your

```
 ListEditor<ClaseProxy, ClaseEditor>
```

If user create one, its okay, then if user edit it. i have a save or cancel options, i save ok, just hide the editor and changes made are ok.

But in user clicks Cancel and if there was some changes on the properties the editor flush(lazely) that changes to the proxy.

Yes i can store the start value on a string then restore with setValue() on the texboxes. But there is some other way (Editor API) that prevents this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `SimpleBeanEditorDriver`, you can do a new call on the `edit` method, without calling `flush` first.

The `SimpleBeanEditorDriver` class reads from the bean into the editors on `edit`, and from the editors into the bean on `flush`.

If you don't want to revert all the editors, but only one of them, remember to call `flush` on every accepted editor change, in order to be able to restore to the last `flush` point. Note that a `flush` call is local and doesn't necessarily have to correspond to a call to the persisting layer.

Example code

```
private Bean currentObject;

/**
 * Start editing the given object.
 */
public void edit(Bean object) {
  this.currentObject = object;
  this.driver.edit(object);
}

/**
 * Call this every time an editor is in a consistent state.
 * (e.g. onBlur event if validation succeeds)
 */
private void save() {
  this.driver.flush(); // saves editors' state into currentObject
}

/**
 * Call this to cancel changes on all editing editors.
 * (e.g. onBlur event if validation fails)
 */
private void revert() {
  this.driver.edit(currentObject); // reloads currentObject into editors
}

/**
 * Stores all pending changes to the server.
 * Remember to validate all editors.
 */
public void commit() {
  Bean object = this.driver.flush();
  Server.persist(object);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes. On the cancel button, do a fire() without building any request. What the editor does never effects the original proxy, it is immutable.  The flush only gives you a copy (unless you are using the RequestFactoryEditorDriver then it returns the context you sent into it with the `driver.edit(proxy,ctx)` .   The fire() without a request clears the edit proxy copy if the user wants to edit again it won't get an error that it is already being editted.

Comment: EditorDriver.flush() doesn't return a copy with SimpleBeanEditorDriver, it asks all subeditors to flush their changes back into the original object. Or am I misunderstand what you mean by 'gives you a copy'?

Comment: In the simple beans driver flush gives you the editable copy of the proxy.  The original proxy is the same as when you first retrieved it.  The term flush makes it seem like it may flush the edited changed back to the original proxy but it doesn't.

Comment: SimpleBeanEditorDriver doesn't assume proxies so that it can be used on normal beans, which means it can't make copies of the models it works with. The RequestFactoryEditorDriver does run context.edit before it passes values to editors - perhaps you are thinking of that instead?

Comment: You are right I wasn't thinking SimpleBeanEditorDriver.  Though I was thinking Editor<>.  Though I do use both Editor and RequestFactoryEditorDriver, I haven't ever used SimpleBeanEditorDriver.  So I don't know what flush does for SimpleBeanEditorDriver.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but flush() on Editor<> returns a copy of the edited proxy and RequestFactoryEditorDriver returns the context you called edit() on it with.

Comment: `Editor<>` doesn't support any methods actually, it is just a marker interface. Due to the lack of general reflection in GWT, it is hard to make a generalized way to clone all objects (or at least an efficient, generalized way). Delegates are build around each Editor, and those Delegates only talk to subeditors, or to the specific methods that the Editor interface implements (like ValueAwareEditor has setValue). RequestFactoryEditorDelegate.ensureMutable(T) does the context.edit call, if needed.

Comment: Okay, my mind is screwed up today (it has been a rough one unrelated to work).  I mixed up a the Editor interface and Drivers classes.  Time for happy hour.  Maybe tomorrow will be better.

Comment: first thanks to you guys to take time to answer. Yes iam using a RequestFactoryEditorDriver and i cant call fire with other RequestContext since its a Per request RequestContext. So this cant help me. And if i call fire() all the changes will be made on server side too.

Comment: You probably wait till after a Save button is pressed to build the request then call ctx.fire() and that sends the request.  But if on Cancel you don't build the request and then call ctx.fire() it just clears the editable proxy and doesn't send anything to the server.

Comment: Hi deanna. I fire the RequestContext until all the bean map it's completed! I am using RequestFactoryEditorDriver so i can fire() the driver only once. My Cancel button is just hidding my Editor. I was thinking ing something like driver.flush() inverse. driver.discard()?

Comment: I don't recall anything like a driver.discard() - although that is a great idea.  What I did on cancel was do the ctx = driver.flush() then the ctx.fire() [with no request].  Then when I go into edit mode again I get a new driver and ctx.  If you don't do the ctx.fire() you will get an exception when if you try to go into edit mode again.